# multiple deferred executions vs one time retrieval

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

What is the fastest solution in following scenario:

I have a list of objects, I need to exclude any objects that match rows in a table (SQLCE).

below is two ways of psuedo code.

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
var dbOjbToExclude = dc.Tables.Where(..).Select(r=>r);
foreach (var item in myOriList)
{
     if (!dbObjToExclude.Any(r=>r.prop1==item.prop1 && r.prop2==item.prop2))
         //add item to a new collection
}
```

Above, I guess the db query is run multiple times for each item in the loop? I am only checking two of the many properties of the object. Another approach is to get just a data object collection of objects with just those two properties and check in that collection for matches:

```
DataContext dc = new DataContext();
var dbOjbToExclude = dc.Tables
                           .Where(..)
                           .Select(r=> new HelperObj {r.prop1,r.prop2})
                           .ToList<HelperObj>();
foreach (var item in myOriList)
{
     if (!dbObjToExclude.Any(r=>r.prop1==item.prop1 && r.prop2==item.prop2))
     //add item to a new collection
}
```

which is faster? Like I said, this is sqlce and linq to sql combination, so I am curious to know which is better to do, performance-wise.

Comment: I guess the best way is to materialize the results before using the Any (var dbOjbToExclude = dc.Tables.Where(..).Select(r=>r).ToArray())

Comment: @StefanoAltieri - the size of dataset from db has no impact? memory wise?

Comment: Unless you have thousands ow rows it will be quicker than many roundtrips to the db

Comment: I think the second would be slower because you're doing the same as the first plus creating a new object for each row.

Comment: @PeterRitchie Looks like my knowledge on deferred execution is very limited. For some reason I thought when I select (new MYCUSTOMCLASS {}) in a linq statement, it will execute immediately as opposed to say select (new {}). I guess this is wrong assumption? Instead I should to a ToList() or something such, to execute immediately? My second was 'meant to' execute immediately.

Comment: @brian That should be deferred too.  the `Where` and `Select` are creating new entity objects (the same basic thing) and they're deferred (BTW, you don't need the `.Select(r=>r)` in your first example, `Where` does that for you).  If you don't want it deferred then `ToList`/`ToArray` would do that.  If you get a lot of data, that may fail though.  Deferred execution will break up the data into row chucks for processing...

Comment: @PeterRitchie Thank you. I always thought 'new'ing to a custom class will cause immediate materialization as opposed to 'new'ing to a anonymous class. Know I know they are both the sort of the same.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the difference is really between multiple calls and one single call. In both cases, the query against the DB will occur at the point where the foreach loop needs the result list. The difference is that the first query will return the entire table, but the second query will return only the couple fields you're asking for. So I would say the second would be more efficient.